# jQuery double tab to replace hover on links

Tags: jquery, hover, touch, tap

I'm using the following code for touch devices.
My page has several div's that serve as links.
The first tap essentially acts as a "hover", enabling the class (.active).
The second tap serves as a click where the url is taken from the data-url attribute.

```
$(".story").on({'touchstart':
    function(){
        $(".active").removeClass("active"); //Deactivate "active" elements
        $(this).stop(true,true).addClass("active",300).children(".blurb").delay(300).fadeIn(350,function(){
            $(this).click(function(){var url = $(this).data("url"); window.location.href = url;})
        });
    }
});
```

My problem is if a user taps once on an element (say #story1), then taps on a DIFFERENT element (#story2), then goes back and taps on #story1, it launches the link as opposed to the .active class.

I assume I need to stop that callback function from triggering if the user leaves the current element. Can anyone help shed some light on that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the best solution, but here is the work-around I have come up with.

```
$(".story").on({"touchstart":
    function(){
        var clicked = $(this).data("clicked");
        if (clicked == "0"){
            $(".story").data("clicked","0");
            $(this).data("clicked","1");
            $(".active").removeClass("active");
            $(this).stop(true,true).addClass("active",300).children(".blurb").delay(300).fadeIn(350);                       
        }
        else {
            var url = $(this).data("url");
            window.location.href = url;}
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the fadeIn function takes that own this element so you need declare this in out of the fadeIn function

```
$(".story").on({'touchstart':
    function(){
     var _this = $(this);
        $(".active").removeClass("active"); //Deactivate "active" elements
        $(this).stop(true,true).addClass("active",300).children(".blurb").delay(300).fadeIn(350,function(){
           _this.click(function(){

               var url = _this.data("url"); 
               window.location.href = url;
});
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Good point on the $(this) element, however your solution still produces the same problem. The second tap activates the link regardless of if the element is ".active".